# Invalid error: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, server

Database.LoadDataSet working incorrect with SQL Server 2017 database.

We are migrating our database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2017. Database is created with compatiblity mode 100 - to be compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2. I got stuck with some old code, which produces not informative exception.

There is a problem with command Database.LoadDataSet, which is calling stored procedure, which accepts 2 parameters. With SQL Server 2008 R2 it works just fine, but with SQL Server 2017 it fails.The error is that there are not enough SQL parameters. But the funny part is that there are enough parameters passed. I am trying to find a solution, compared old database with new one, and properties seem to be the same for database and stored procedure.

.NET CLR Version on IIS App pool:  2.0

.NET target Framework version: 3.5

```
//.NET C# code:
DataSet dataset;
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
db.LoadDataSet(
"USP_Proc", 
dataset, 
new string[] {"Titles", "Config", "Teams"}, 
Request.QueryString["Type"], 
int.Parse(Request.QueryString["BranchID"]));


//SQL Procedure:

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Proc]
@BranchType VARCHAR (15), @BranchId [dbo].[ID]
AS
SELECT 
  TitleId, Title 
FROM vOperatorTitles
ORDER BY Title

IF @BranchType = 'L'
BEGIN
  SELECT OperatorTeams 
  FROM tCustomerConfig 
  WHERE CustomerId = @BranchId

  SELECT TeamId, TeamName 
  FROM tTeams
  WHERE CustomerId = @BranchId
END

SELECT count(*) as ISSTAGEMANAGEMENT   
FROM tfeature_branch 
WHERE
   branchid=@BranchId and 
   systemside=@BranchType and 
   featureid = (select featureid from tfeature where featurecode= 'somecode')









Expected: there is no errors (as on environments which use old SQL Server)

Actual: 
When calling db.LoadDataSet, there is an error:

[InvalidOperationException: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure.]
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(String storedProcedureName, Object[] parameterValues) +384
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.LoadDataSet(String storedProcedureName, DataSet dataSet, String[] tableNames, Object[] parameterValues) +42
   SupportConsole.Pagelets.OperatorAdd.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Source\Pagelets\OperatorAdd.ascx.cs:88
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `.LoadDataSet` method, where is that documented?

Comment: What is the value of `Request.QueryString["Type"]`? _Please check in the `Immediate Window`?_

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb744811(v=pandp.31)

Comment: Values: Type: 'L', BranchId: 3

Comment: are you able to run the sp directly using the `exec` command: `exec [dbo].[USP_Proc] BranchType = 'L', BranchId=3`

Comment: Yes, it works, when passing variables names with @

Comment: Are you using MYSQL or SQL Server?  I think you may need to update you connection parameters.  Also it is a good idea to force project to fully recompile.  I wold copy bin folder and then delete and compile which will force all intermediate object files to get updated.

Comment: We are using MS SQL Server 2017. With SQL Server 2008 R2 it works without any problems. Connection parameters are actual, and project was fully recompiled too, it did not help.

Comment: Your parameters should be in an array...

Comment: Adding parameters to array did not solve the issue for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters should be in an array

```
db.LoadDataSet("USP_Proc", 
    dataset, 
    new string[] {"Titles", "Config", "Teams"}, 
    new object[] { Request.QueryString["Type"], int.Parse(Request.QueryString        
                  ["BranchID"])});
```

Comment: Unforntunately it did not help. Still the same issue.